# Alternative to `pkill` or `pgrep -f` on cygwin?

Tags: kill, ps, cygwin

Suppose I have started my process like:

```
java -DSOME_STRING -jar foo.jar
```

Then on linux, I can use the following to find or kill this process:

```
pgrep -f SOME_STRING
pkill -f SOME_STRING
```

However this doesn't seem to work on cygwin. Can anyone suggest an alternative for these tools in cygwin?

Comment: Doesn't work in what way?  Doesn't kill the process, doesn't find the process to kill it?  Gives an error?

Comment: pgrep doesn't find the process. pkill doesn't kill the process.

Comment: Here are implementations of `killall` and `pidof` crafted for Cygwin. Depends on Python 2/ - https://github.com/kata198/cygwin-ps-misc

Answer (score 18):

pkill and pgrep certainly exist within Cygwin, in the [procps](http://cygwin.com/packages/procps/procps-3.2.7-1) package (you can search cygwin packages [here](http://cygwin.com/packages/)).

It appears to work for me,

```
tony:~$ nohup sleep 100983 &
[1] 5476
tony:~$ nohup: ignoring input and appending output to `nohup.out'
tony:~$
tony:~$ ps -ef | grep sleep
    tony    5476    2696   2  23:28:53 /usr/bin/sleep
tony:~$ pkill -f sleep
[1]+  Terminated              nohup sleep 100983
tony:~$
```

and

```
tony:~$ nohup sleep 837746 &
[1] 228
tony:~$ nohup: ignoring input and appending output to `nohup.out'
tony:~$ pgrep -f 837746
228
tony:~$ pkill -f 837746
[1]+  Terminated              nohup sleep 837746
tony:~$
```

**Update: okay, tested with java.  Executing java from the Cygwin command line does not result in the java string being placed into `/proc/<pid>/cmdline`, that just contains `-bash`.
This appears to be a limitation of Cygwin.**

```
tony:~$ java -Dsomething=valid -jar Captor.jar &
[1] 2700
tony:~$ ps -ef
     UID     PID    PPID TTY     STIME COMMAND
    tony    4164       1   ?    Aug 21 /usr/bin/mintty
    tony    4676    4164   0    Aug 21 /usr/bin/bash
    tony    5776    4676   0    Aug 23 /usr/bin/ssh
    tony    5148       1   ?  23:53:03 /usr/bin/mintty
    tony    5332    5148   1  23:53:03 /usr/bin/bash
    tony    5816       1   ?  00:04:16 /usr/bin/mintty
    tony    5432    5816   2  00:04:16 /usr/bin/bash
    tony    2700    5432   2  00:04:34 /cygdrive/c/Windows/system32/java
    tony    2232    5432   2  00:04:39 /usr/bin/ps
tony:~$ pgrep -f something
tony:~$ cat /proc/2700/cmdline
-bash
tony:~$
tony:~$ cat /proc/2700/exename
/cygdrive/c/Windows/system32/java
```

I suspect therefore, the answer is you can't do this with a Cygwin tool, you would need a Windows specific tool.

Comment: Your example is substantially different than the one the OP is trying. You matched the name of the process rather than an arbitrary string in it's arguments. Can you test the latter and see if that works?

Comment: seems to work fine

Comment: It seems procps is not available for x64 cygwin.

Comment: @thameera try package `procps-ng`.

Comment: `apt-cyg install procps-ng` with newest cygwin

Comment: to install apt-cyg: `wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/transcode-open/apt-cyg/master/apt-cyg && install apt-cyg /bin`

Answer (score 9):

In older Cygwin versions, there is a `procps` package that you can install to get the same functionality with the same commands.

In newer Cygwin versions, the `procps` package no longer exists and is replaced by package `procps-ng`.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer

Comment: I also needed to install the `libproc2_0` package to get rid of the error "C:/tools/cygwin/bin/pgrep.exe: error while loading shared libraries: cygproc2-0.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"

Answer (score 6):

The Cygwin utilities work like the Linux ones, but they only work on Cygwin processes. For Windows processes, you need to use Windows utilities, such as the ones from [Sysinternals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb842062). [PsKill](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896683) can kill processes by name.

Comment: as can the native `taskkill /f /im procname.exe`

Comment: `ps` also shows Windows processes with the `-W` switch

Comment: or `tasklist | findstr procname`